# Why are there missing apiconnect modules after installing?

Tags: node.js, apiconnect

On my Windows 10 pc, before installing apiconnect, *npm list* gives a very short list

```
npm list -g --depth=0
C:\Program Files\nodejs
+-- npm@6.4.1
`-- windows-build-tools@5.1.0
```

After installing apiconnect with an administrator level command prompt and then performing a list of installed modules, there are still 4 apiconnect modules missing.

```
npm list -g --depth=0
C:\Program Files\nodejs
+-- apiconnect@3.0.17
+-- npm@6.4.1
`-- windows-build-tools@5.1.0

npm ERR! missing: apiconnect-cli-util@^9.x, required by apiconnect-cli-pm@4.0.1
npm ERR! missing: apiconnect-collective-controller-api@^3.x, required by apiconnect-cli-pm@4.0.1
npm ERR! missing: apiconnect-project@^1.x, required by microgateway@1.6.8
npm ERR! invalid: apiconnect-config@2.0.0 C:\Program     Files\nodejs\node_modules\apiconnect\node_modules\microgateway\node_modules\apiconnect-config
```

So I installed all the missing modules, but now the *npm list* gives

```
npm list -g --depth=0
C:\Program Files\nodejs
+-- apiconnect@3.0.17
+-- apiconnect-cli-util@9.0.0
+-- apiconnect-collective-controller-api@3.2.1
+-- apiconnect-config@2.0.0
+-- apiconnect-project@2.0.0
+-- npm@6.4.1
`-- windows-build-tools@5.1.0

npm ERR! missing: apiconnect-cli-util@^9.x, required by apiconnect-cli-pm@4.0.1
npm ERR! missing: apiconnect-collective-controller-api@^3.x, required by apiconnect-cli-pm@4.0.1
npm ERR! missing: apiconnect-project@^1.x, required by microgateway@1.6.8
npm ERR! invalid: apiconnect-config@2.0.0 C:\Program     Files\nodejs\node_modules\apiconnect\node_modules\microgateway\node_modules\apiconnect-config
```

How can I get the *ERR! missing* errors to go away? Do I really need to worry about it?

Thanks for your help, Russ.

Answer (score 1):

Is everything working as expected?

I had a lot of difficulty installing apiconnect locally on my Windows 7 machine behind a corporate firewall. Through this, I came to the conclusion that some packages are required for unix installs and are not needed for Windows and so I could dismiss some of the errors.

I can't remember the exact names of those packages, but this could be the same issue.